# Why doesn't a tap gesture recognizer work when creating a variable?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am new to Swift, and I have been working on a project and ran into a peculiar issue that I fixed, but wasn't quite sure why the solution worked.

I have a class `UserViewController` where I do something like:

```
class UserViewController: UIViewController {

    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "profilepic")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30) //CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * imageView.bounds.size.width
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        return imageView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        view.addSubview(profileImageView)

        profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
        profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfilePicture))
        profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

I was trying to add a tap gesture recognizer to my `UIImageView`. What I was doing before was actually adding the recognizer in my initialization for `profileImageView` like this:

```
let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "profilepic")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30) //CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * imageView.bounds.size.width
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfilePicture))
    profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return imageView
    }()
```

When I was doing this, the recognizer was not working (I would tap on the image and nothing would happen, the handler function was never invoked). When I pulled out the three lines that created/added the gesture recognizer to my image view, and moved them into `setupView()` the tap was recognized, and everything worked as expected.

For the betterment of my understanding, why is this the case? Why can't I add the gesture recognize in the initialization of my image view and have it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You were modifying the not-yet returned variable in these two lines in your old code:

```
profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Replace `profileImageView` with `imageView` and it will work.